# como bloquear str en int(input())

Tags: python, input

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un listado para registrar personas y trato de bloquear las letras pero no me resulta he buscado pero no encuentro nada. Aca dejo el codigo.

```python
Persona = []
Edad = []


from unidecode import unidecode


aux=0

while aux==0:
    print('Directorio de Personas: \n 1) Ingresar Persona \n 2) Eliminar Persona \n 3) Modificar Nombre y Apellido y/o edad \n 4) Listado de Personas y Edad \n 5) Salir')
    aux1=int(input('Opción: '))
    print('')
    
    if aux1==1:
        i=unidecode(input('Ingrese su Nombre y Apellido: '))
        
        if i not in Persona:
            Persona.append(i)
            aux2=0
            
            while aux2==0:
                print('')
                aux3=int(input('Ingrese su Edad: '))
                
                if aux3>0:
                    Edad.append(aux3)
                    
                    print('')
                    print('Se ha registrado exitosamente.')
                    print('')
                    break
                    aux=0
                    
                elif aux3<0:
                    print('')
                    print('Por favor ingrese una edad válida.')
                    aux2==0
                    
        elif i in Persona:
            aux=0
            print('')
            print('La persona ya se encuentra registrada en el listado.')
    elif aux1==2:
        i=unidecode(input(print('Introduzca el Nombre, Apellidos y Edad de la persona que desea eliminar: ')).lower())
        if i not in Persona:
            print('')
            print('La persona que desea eliminar no se encuentra en el listado.')
            aux=0
    #elif i in Persona:
        p=(Persona.index(i))
        del Persona[p]
        del Edad[p]
        index=1
        print('')
        for (Persona,Edad) in zip(Persona,Edad):
            print('')
            print(f'{index}.-{Persona} : Edad {Edad}')
            index=index+1
            print('')
            
            
            
    #elif aux1==4:
        index=1
        #for (Persona,Edad) in zip(Persona,Edad):
            #print(f'{index}.-{Persona} : Edad {Edad}')
            #index=index+1
        
    elif aux1==5:
        aux=1
        print('')
        print('Adios')

    elif aux1>5:
        print('')
        print('La opción elegída no es valida, por favor ingrese una opción dentro del listado.')
        
    #elif aux1:
            #print('')
            #print('Por Favor ingrese una opcion valida.')
        
        aux=0
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres exactamente con bloquear a la letras?

Comment: Intenta usar también el else: if i not in Persona: pass; else: pass; En ves de if i not in Persona: pass elif i not in Persona: pass

Comment: También conseguí un error en tu código que afectará el resultado: i=input("Introduzca el nombre, apellido, edad de la persona que desea eliminar");

Comment: Tu guardas los resultados de esta manera: Persona="Daniel"; Edad="Daniel"; y el error está que quieres obtener el resultado de esta manera: "Ingrese nombre, edad, etc.."

Comment: "Juan 21" y al momento de buscarlo haces: si "Juan 21" es igual a Juan elimino a juan, si no no lo elimino.

Comment: El programa te dira que es falso porque la cadena "Juan 21" no es la misma que Juan

Comment: Tu solución sería ya sea pidiendo dos entradas diferentes o análisando la cadena y separando los datos: `i=input("Ingrese el nombre de la persona a eliminar");edad=input("Ingrese su edad);`. i=input("Ingrese su nombre y su edad").split(" ");#Separamos las palabras en una lista.     if i[0] in Persona: #Eliminamos esa persona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver. Si entendi bien lo que quieres hacer es hacer que en un input, solo haya numeros. ¿Esto es por mero diseño o por un error? Si ese es el caso usa esto:

```
def main():
    while True:
        try:
            E = int(input("Ingrese un valor numerico: "))
            #Hacer operaciones numericas
            print(E+2)
            break #Si todo va bien se sale del bucle
        except ValueError:
            #Como no se le puede sumar 2 a una string arrojara este error
            print("Debe ingresar un valor numerico")
            #Ademas, como no hay ningun break. El bucle se repetira
            #hasta que no se produzca este error.


main()
```

Comment: Es por mero diseño, ademas lo trato de hacer asi por un trabajo que tiene que tener la menor cantidad de errores por eso lo necesito y el tema es que no se como ponerlo porque estoy recien empezando a programar

Comment: Bueno, lamento decirte que creo que eso no es posible. La funcion input() solo tiene un parametro, no es mas personalizable ni nada.

Comment: Lo mas cercano a lo que quieres hacer es lo que programe ahi, manejar el error con un try(intentar ejecutar tal codigo) y despues un except (si ocurre tal error hacer tal accion), dentro de un bucle. Donde hasta que no se ingrese un valor numerico no se pueda salir.